# 7 Day Return/Retention Rate

Tags: postgresql

I've been trying to calculate 7 Day Return Rate (also known as Classic Retention Rate, as described here: https://www.braze.com/blog/calculate-retention-rate/) and then taking a 30 day average to reduce noise in Postgresql.

However, I'm sure I'm doing something wrong. First of all, the numbers look waaay higher than intuitively I feel they should be (generally around 5% for the rest of the sector). Also, I believe the first 7 days should show 0, as theoretically users should take at least 7 days to count as a "return". However, I get around 40-70%, as shown below.

Would someone mind taking a look at the code below and seeing if there are any errors? 7 Day Return Rate is a really common metric for apps, and I haven't found any questions using postgresql that calculate it to this level of sophistication on Stack Exchange (or even the rest of the web), so I feel like a solid response could be very useful to a lot of people.

Sample data

```
Wednesday, August 1, 2018 12:00 AM    71.14
Thursday, August 2, 2018 12:00 AM     55.44
Friday, August 3, 2018 12:00 AM       50.09
Saturday, August 4, 2018 12:00 AM     45.81
Sunday, August 5, 2018 12:00 AM       43.27
Monday, August 6, 2018 12:00 AM       40.61
Tuesday, August 7, 2018 12:00 AM      39.38
Wednesday, August 8, 2018 12:00 AM    38.46
Thursday, August 9, 2018 12:00 AM     36.81
Friday, August 10, 2018 12:00 AM      35.94
```

```
with

user_first_event as (
    select distinct id, min(timestamp)::date as first_event_date
    from log
    where 
        timestamp <= current_date
        and timestamp >= {{start_date}} and timestamp <= {{end_date}}
    group by id),

event as (
    select distinct id, timestamp::date as user_event_date
    from log
    where timestamp <= current_date and timestamp >= {{start_date}}),

gap as (
    select 
        user_first_event.id, 
        user_first_event.first_event_date,
        event.user_event_date,
        event.user_event_date - user_first_event.first_event_date as days_since_signup
    from user_first_event
    join event on user_first_event.id = event.id
    where user_first_event.first_event_date <= event.user_event_date),

conversion_rate as (
select
    first_event_date,
    (sum(case when days_since_signup = 7 then 1 else 0 end) * 100.0 /
        count(distinct id)
      ) as seven_day_retention_rate
from gap
group by first_event_date
)

SELECT first_event_date,  
       AVG(seven_day_retention_rate)
            OVER(ORDER BY first_event_date ROWS BETWEEN 29 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS rolling_avg_retention_rate
FROM conversion_rate
```

Comment: Your link describes three different ways of calculating retention rate, which are you interested in?

Comment: Hey, apologies - it is the first one ("classic retention rate"). I've clarified this in the question. Basically for XX users who used the app on day 0, I am trying to calculate what % returned on the 7th day (i.e. if 10 users used the app on day 0 and 5 of them used it again on day 7, return rate would be 50%). I've then applied a 30-day rolling average to smooth the curves. cc @GeorgeS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a bit easier than your query makes it seem, you can actually do it with just one subquery and one out query as follows:

```
select first_event_date
 , avg(seven_day_return) as seven_day_return_day_only
 , avg( avg(seven_day_return) ) OVER(ORDER BY first_event_date asc ROWS BETWEEN 29 preceding AND CURRENT ROW ) AS thirty_day_rolling_retention
from (
  --inner query to get value for user, 1 if they retain and 0 if they do not
  select min(timestamp)::date as first_event_date
   , case when array_agg(timestamp::date) @> ARRAY[ (min(timestamp)::date + 7) ] then 1 else 0 end as seven_day_return
  from log
  group by id ) t

group by t.first_event_date;
```

Note that this weights each *day* equally rather than each *user* equally across days. If you want to weight the average by user across days then you can update the outer calculation using more aggregates and windows to compute the value with weightings.

Reference: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ee17e/1/0

If you don't have access to array_agg (but have access to window functions) you can use:

```
select first_event_date
 , avg(seven_day_return) as day_seven_day_return
 , avg( avg(seven_day_return) ) OVER(ORDER BY first_event_date asc ROWS BETWEEN 29 preceding AND CURRENT ROW ) AS thirty_day_rolling_retention
from (
  --inner query to get value for user
  select min(timestamp)::date as first_event_date
   , case when exists(select 1 from log l2 where l2.id = log.id and l2.timestamp::date = min(log.timestamp)::date + 7) then 1 else 0 end as seven_day_return
  from log
  group by id ) t

group by t.first_event_date;
```

Comment: I love this solution - very elegant and a lot better than anything I've seen elsewhere. However, looks like I'm on a previous version of Postgre (v8.0.2) that doesn't have the array_agg function. While I ask if it can be installed (I'm on a work system), I wonder if there's any alternatives?

Comment: Hmm, the `array_agg` can be replaced with something like: `, case when exists(select 1 from log l2 where l2.id = log.id and l2.timestamp::date = min(log.timestamp)::date + 7) then 1 else 0 end as seven_day_return` in this case I'd suggest using a table alias for both the original log table and the log table in the `exists` clause for clarity

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out.